# Как передать в функцию переменное число аргументов 1 типа в с++ стиле?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17, метапрограммирование

Как передать в функцию переменное число аргументов 1 типа в с++ стиле?

у меня есть функция

```
template<class... args>
void Test (args... aArgs)
{

}
```

проблема в том, что aArgs могут быть разных типов, а я хочу чтоб были одного

Comment: можно использовать `std::initializer_list<T>` вместо parameter pack

Comment: либо же если хочется использовать parameter pack, проверять каждый аргумент с помощью `std::is_same_v`

Comment: Зачем 1 типа? Ладно еще 2, но если нужен лишь 1 тип - то просто уберите шаблон и используйте ваш тип